# How to create a stripe subscription with trial, when subscription created in trial mode element not accepting the secrete key from subscription object

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm trying to implement stripe payment on my web app, Node and react is the stack.

- creating a stripe subscription in backend

```
      newSubscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
        customer: {{customerid},
        items: [
          {
            price: {{price}},
          },
        ],
        payment_behavior: 'default_incomplete',
        expand: ['pending_setup_intent'],
        trial_period_days: 7,
        off_session: true,
      });
```

- when i add trail period i'm getting client secrete something like 'seti_XXXXX'.
- when there is no trail i'm getting client secrete as 'pi_XXX'.
- when i'm using payment intent secrete key stripe element is working and transaction is happening.
- when i i use setup intent client secrete, that si'm getting when trial active is not working with stripe element. it show some error saying payment intent not found.

i tried to pass both client secretes to element, but when trail is active. In that case i'm getting the setup intent client secrete so that the element throughs some error.
`

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "resource_missing",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/resource-missing",
    "message": "No such payment_intent: 'seti_XXXXXXXXXXXXX'",
    "param": "intent",
    "request_log_url": "https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_XXXXXXXXXXX",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

`
how to solve this issue, i want trail activated subscription, when trails ends the user must be credited with that amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you include a trial period in your subscription, a $0 invoice is generated initially, which doesn't require payment. This way you are creating a SetupIntent, instead of PaymentIntent. You can see it in the ID prefix: `seti_…`. Since there is no payment happening right away, SetupIntent allows you to store the payment details, which, in turn, the subscription can use for recurring payments.

Therefore, you should use the [confirmSetup method](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=web#web-submit-payment-details), when the user submits the form.

Comment: everything i need to do is to use setup method instead of a checkout method since there is no actual payment is taken place because of trial. That really helps me. Thank you.